# call python script from PHP index out of range

Tags: php, python, exec

I'm calling a python script from my PHP code, I need to pass 7 variable: a few strings, a couple of array and a matrix.

I tried to use both Shell_Exec and exec(), but I get always the same problem:

```
matrixdata = sys.argv[7]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The first thought was " I passed the wrong number of variable ", but checking they are 7. 
This is my python code:

```
 listlabel = str(sys.argv[2])
 listdata = (sys.argv[1])
 typechart = str(sys.argv[3])
 name = str(sys.argv[4])
 typedata = str(sys.argv[5])
 title = str(sys.argv[6])
 matrixdata = sys.argv[7] //this is the matrix
```

This is my PHP Lines to call it

```
//json encoding for the array:
$total = json_encode(compact($listlabel));
$event = json_encode(compact($listdata));
$event = json_encode(compact($matrixdata));


exec("python ../home/path../create_chart.py $total $event $chart $name $typedata $title $matrixdata", $output);
//all the parameters exist and the path is correct
```

I'm passing 7 arguments, I'm getting 7 arguments. I don't understand where the problem is.

Before to added the last matrix, this line was working with 7 elements, instead of 7, I also tried with 8 elements and 9 instead of 7, but no luck.

Let me know if someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: dump out sys.argv and see what really got passed in, then do `$cmd = "python .... $matrixdata"; var_dump($cmd);` to see what you're generating in php. just because it LOOKS like it should work, doesn't mean it actually will, especially when you're passing things through a shell.

Comment: Even worse, using dd(exec..) is printing only the first variable, but the others variable are not empty...

Comment: Have you tried [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)?

Comment: nothing ._. this is the print of my string        '"'{"events":["Informational","Low","Critical","High"]}'"'

Comment: In the end I solved, adding an extra variable that contain a string, so I'm passing 8 arguments instead of 7, I have no really idea why.